# Parsing Long value to Long?

Tags: java, boxing

I'm working with a quite old codebase, so much of deprecated or outdated code exists. Most of it is simple pre-boxing.

But this one raised a question with me:

```
private java.lang.Long version = Long.valueOf(-1L);
```

Does the `-1L` not define the value as a Long already? Was this even possible before?

Note it's not `-1l` but `-1L`.

I would understand if it was written as `-1` or even `-1l`. Can someone explain to me what is going on?

Comment: "An integer literal is of type `long` if it ends with the letter `L` or `l`" - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: I've asked this to my collegues yesterday, And they weren't sure. It must be that we might be too young to know. But I do have the feel this is a legit question and the downvotes is a bit of a pity. I did now realise that assuming 1L would be a Long is a silly thing to assume. I do wonder why they allow both l and L now though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-1l` and `-1L` are the same - both are primitive `long` literals.

`Long.valueOf()` returns a `Long` instance having the same value as the passed primitive.

It's important to note that `Long.valueOf()` uses the `LongCache` when you pass small values to it (i.e. values between -128 and 127), and therefore it doesn't have to create a new `Long` instance.

Simply assigning `Long version = -1L;` would auto-box the `-1L` primitive literal to a `Long`. Whether a new `Long` instance will be created by the auto-boxing or the compiler will be smart enough to use the `LongCache` depends on the compiler. I guess whoever wrote the code you posted didn't want to rely on the compiler doing the smart thing.

Comment: Allright, that explains I assumed the 1L meant Long. when I think about it that makes sense since writing a value directly is impossible with a pointer.

Just thinking wrong on my side. Pity of all the downvotes :-)

Comment: Note that some of this code is from 2005 not sure if the compiler was smart enough back then.